# In Microsoft Power Automate, is there a way to look at a previous version of a Flow?

Tags: power-automate

In Microsoft Power Automate, is there a way to look at a previous version of a Flow?

If I have done some work on a flow and it does not work anymore because of the additions and changes, is there a way to revert to a previous version that worked?

Comment: If you still have a trace of an execution of that earlier version of the flow, the trace will show you that version of the code.  I don't believe there is a way to revert just that flow, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no versioning support in Power Automate. So unless you made a copy of the flow there is no previous version you can roll back to.